# Singleton object lifetime is process or appdomain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, singleton

Recently I have been asked a question in an interview

> Singleton pattern guarantees creating only a single object of a class
>   in a process or app domain level?

Comment: it is per appdomain as per my understanding

Comment: I also told the same answer but interviewer were asking for reference to support my answer.

Comment: app domain is under CLR while process runs under OS, and if object is a managed then it's lifetime is with appdomain

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/application-domains#the-benefits-of-isolating-applications <- based on this section, I change my former comment to "App Domain". Silly question for an interview, though.

Answer (score 0):

The C# specification about static fields states:

> I.8.4.3 Static fields are always restricted to a single application domain basis (see §I.12.5), but they can also be allocated on a per-thread basis

You can get more information [reading the CLI spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).

Comment: but its not necessary that static has been used to implement singleton. If I use private constructor ?

Comment: Can you give me an example ? Do you mean that you instance the object yourself and then keep it alive for the whole lifetime of the application ?